# Connection Pooling in flask using couchbase as database

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, flask, couchbase, connection-pooling

I am a newbie to flask. I need to implement connection pooling in flask, the following is my software stack:
1. Flask - 0.12.2
2. Python version - 3.4.3
3. Python couchbase driver version - 2.2.1
4. Couchbase version - 4.5.0-2601 Community Edition (build-2601)

My requirement is - at server startup - repeatedly run 3-4 processes after every 'n' seconds i.e. some process runs every 1 second, some run every 5 seconds etc. I used the "threading" module in python to execute running these parallel processes. 
I did not want to create & close connection for above processes, so I create required connections to couchbase buckets at flask start up as below:
(The following lines of code are in "app.py" file)

```
 cbBkt1Conn = Couchbase.connect(host=<host_name>, 
 bucket=<bucket1>, password=<bucket1Password>)
 cbBkt2Conn = Couchbase.connect(host=<host_name>, 
 bucket=<bucket3>, password=<bucket3Password>)
 cbBkt3Conn = Couchbase.connect(host=<host_name>, 
 bucket=<bucket3>, password=<bucket3Password>)
```

etc

But, when flask starts after a 3-4 runs I get the following exception:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/couchbase/n1ql.py", line 384, 
 in __iter__
  self._start()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/couchbase/n1ql.py", line 297, 
 in _start
 cross_bucket=self._params.cross_bucket)

 couchbase.exceptions.ObjectThreadError: <Couldn't lock. If LOCKMODE_WAIT 
 was passed, then this means that something has gone wrong internally. 
 Otherwise, this means you are using the Connection object from multiple 
 threads. This is not allowed (without an explicit lockmode=LOCKMODE_WAIT 
 constructor argument, C Source=(src/oputil.c,428)>
```

On further investigation I found that since I am using the same connection object across multiple threads, this was not permitted (as per above error trace & links below):

http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client-2.2.1/api/threads.html

The links suggest to use "threading" with "LOCKMODE_WAIT" option, but this defeats the entire purpose.

I also came across SQLALCHEMY, but this does not supports couchbase

Query:
1) How do I implement connection pooling in Flask?
Please guide me to an example / reference to implement this.

Thanks,
Sachin Vyas.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off creating new connections in a threading environment. (And maybe think about why you don't want to share to begin with).

It is best to think of connections like an old-style house lines. If one person picks up and dials in the living room, then anyone who wants to make a call on the same line will receive the same conversation. If he picks up the phone and starts calling for pizza, then the people that are using the phone will be interrupted and he won't get his pizza.

There are two options: either the second person who wants to use the house will need to wait until the line is free, or open a new connection for each person in the house.

Comment: I'd note that in the Couchbase Python client, we unlock the GIL on entry and we can pipeline multiple operations enqueued, thought the IO loop is driven only once in that particular case.  Generally with Couchbase, we do recommend sharing a client, but there are a lot of factors.